# How do I wait for the tests in a file to finish to start tests in another file using Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, tdd

I am using a sqlite database for the tests using Jest and before all test I truncate the tables but when I separate the tests in files it truncates the tables at the same time the tests in another file is running. Is that correct? There is any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async - await` to sync action in JS

Comment: I am using and I have already tried to use the jest done parameter but doesn't help in this case